# Why am I getting 'permission denied' cifs?

Tags: server, 20.04, .desktop

Recently I had to re-install Ubuntu Server 20.04, which had a zfs pool. After the installation, I was able to restore the zfs volume.

But I cannot write to that volume from an Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, receiving a 'permission denied' error. Why am I getting this error? Could it be something with the restoration of the zfs volume? Even root cannot write to this smb share.

```
workstation:
  $ id
  uid=1000(larry) gid=1000(larry) groups=1000(larry),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare),997(docker)

  $ mount | grep data
  //192.168.10.20/data on /mnt/data type cifs 
  (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=larry,uid=1000,noforceuid,gid=1000,
  noforcegid,addr=192.168.10.20,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,
  soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,
  bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)

server:
  $ id
  uid=1000(larry) gid=1000(larry) groups=1000(larry),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lxd)
  
  $ zfs get all tank/data
  NAME       PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
  tank/data  type                  filesystem             -
  tank/data  setuid                on                     default
  tank/data  readonly              off                    default
  tank/data  aclinherit            restricted             default
  tank/data  sharesmb              off                    default

  From /etc/samba/smb.conf:
  [global]
         workgroup = WORKGROUP
         server string = Samba Server
         netbios name = ubuntu
         security = user
         map to guest = bad user
         dns proxy = no
         [data]
         path = /tank/data
         browsable =yes
         writable = yes
         guest ok = yes
         read only = no
         create mask = 644

List directories:
  Server:
    $ ls -ld Larry*
    drwxr-xr-x 55 larry larry 118 Apr  6 15:01 Larry/
    drwxr-xr-x  2 larry larry   2 Sep 10 06:56 Larry2/

  Workstation:
    $ ls -ld /mnt/data/Larry*
    drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry 0 Sep 10 08:56 /mnt/data/Larry/
    drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry 0 Sep 10 08:56 /mnt/data/Larry2/

Perform tests:
  Server:
    $ touch Larry/test
    $ touch Larry2/test
    $ rm Larry/test Larry2/test

  Workstation:
    $ touch /mnt/data/Larry/test
    touch: cannot touch '/mnt/data/Larry/test': Permission denied
    $ touch /mnt/data/Larry2/test
    touch: cannot touch '/mnt/data/Larry2/test': Permission denied
    $ sudo touch /mnt/data/Larry/test
    touch: cannot touch '/mnt/data/Larry/test': Permission denied
```

Comment: Have you tried using -rf flag with the touch command  ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to redo permissions on the zfs datasets, something like:

```
chown -R me:me /tank/dataset1
```